# Bluemix MobileFirstStarter MySQL ClassNotFoundException Error

Tags: mysql, containers, ibm-cloud, ibm-mobilefirst

I have created a MobileFirst Container and a MySQL service in Bluemix and have connected them with a Cloud Foundry application. I deployed my mobile app and the adapter to the Worklight Console(container). When I try to get some data through the mobile app, the Worklight log gives me the following error:

> java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Class com.mysql.jdbc.Driver not
>   found in Worklight platform or project /MobileFirstStarter

How can I solve this problem? Or, where can I upload the driver?

Answer (score 2):

MySQL DB Service is not supported with MobileFirst Containers on IBM Bluemix. Currently it supports sqldb & Cloudant only. I recommend you to try Cloudant DB.